# How would I apply condition of dates from the two column in below query to get the expected result

Tags: sql

I want arrival should be from 2020, in case arrival is in 2019, then reservation_date should be later 
 to 1st June 2019.Also query must work on sql developer.

```
  SELECT
    r.reservation_id,
    re.name,
    d.name AS d_name,
    r.status,
    r.arrival_date,
    r.reservation_date,
    r.type
FROM
    reservation           r
    JOIN resorti18n            re ON ( r.resort_id = re.resort_id )
    JOIN distributionchannel   d ON ( d.distributionchannel_id = r.distributionchannel_id )
WHERE
    re.name = 'Banjaard'
    AND r.status IN (
        12,
        21
    )
    AND r.type = 'r'
    AND d.code LIKE 'DB%'
    AND r.arrival_date BETWEEN '01-JAN-19' AND '31-DEC-20'
ORDER BY
    d.name ASC,
    r.arrival_date DESC;
```

Comment: what is your purpose ?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would help.  And your first two sentences conflict.  There is no arrive in 2019, if you only want arrivals in 2020.

Answer (score 0):

You might possibly try:

```
WHERE
    re.name = 'Banjaard'
    AND r.status IN (
        12,
        21
    )
    AND r.type = 'r'
    AND d.code LIKE 'DB%'
    AND r.arrival_date BETWEEN '01-JAN-19' AND '31-DEC-20'
    AND r.reservation_date >= CASE WHEN DATEPART(YEAR, r.Arrival_date) = '2019' THEN '01-JUN-2019' ELSE r.reservation_date END
```

Comment: Oracle database

Comment: Your tag said SQL